# Why can't I ask/post any questions...?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Once I asked 2 questions. But after some time, I deleted those.
Now After clicking `Ask Question`, it displays the following:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>   For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>   Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I tried to improve the formatting and clarity of my old questions. But I couldn't get my old questions. Because after asking those questions I deleted them.

Now in my profile,it shows like:

> 0 Questions
>   You have not asked any questions.

How can I ask a question now? Why wasn't I able to find the deleted questions? What is the solution?

Comment: I think, sometimes question title may be same.But question content may be different.If any one find question same like this,give the link.Please...

Comment: You are not being blocked, you are being *warned*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It means, i can ask questions.Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you can ask questions. But if they are not good, on topic questions, you _will_ get blocked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> you're in danger of being blocked

That's not being blocked. Yet.

The message tells you to make sure your question is a good one (hey, you even get links to pages that explain what that means!).

If your next question is not well received, *then* you may get blocked.

---

You should make sure your question are not only of high quality, but are also on topic for the site.

Looking at the titles of your previous (deleted) questions, they seem to have been off-topic.

Comment: Is it possible to see deleted questions like deleted answer..

Comment: Only if they are recent questions. Go to your profile page, to the questions tab - there is a link at the bottom (deleted recent questions)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.

Comment: What is the mean the question is well received? Being answered? Sometimes waiting for several days, although a few answers but not directly solve the problem, what should I do to the question? What if someone help to solve the problem but I don't know what actually did on the problem.

Comment: @Kelvin - well received as determined by the community (votes - up/down/close). A question that is not well received will have more downvotes than upvotes and will most likely be closed - that has nothing to do with it having answers or not.

Comment: What can I do if the question is down vote or how I can improve sometimes to make the down vote question being up vote? Can I have chance to improve it? English is not my native language, I worry my account is being closed and I can't ask any question again. Honestly it helps me a lot in programming technique.

Comment: Following the [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines when editing a question should help - adding relevant detail, clarifying the issue, explaining what you have tried etc... @Kelvin

Comment: Now I know the guidelines in asking question, my question is how I can do for those questions have been down voted?

Comment: @Kelvin - like I said. Go and edit them. Make them good.

Comment: @Oded, do you mean the people will see my reword and consider the cancel the down vote if my word is followed the guideline? I will try by best but seem no one will give the chance. They are keep silent. I am being warned and I stop posting question here.

Comment: They might, @Kelvin - edits do get bumped to the homepage, so others could also see them.

Comment: this system is so bad we should be able to ask as many questions as we want and nobody should be able to block us because some of them may be low quality questions. Completely nonsense

Comment: @theo231022 - if your aim is a wasteland of bad questions and no good answers (because following your suggestion all experts would flee), sure.

Comment: @Oden I mean that blocking is too much. They could at least rate those questions as low quality and then mark them as spam and remove them. But completely blocking users from asking is like they are punishing users.

Comment: They do mark them as low quality - by downvoting them. And they are not spam (we are very specific about what that means). And if someone shows a pattern of low quality posts, why do you think they should be allowed to keep asking? This is not about "punishing users" - it is about keeping the standards of asking high. What you are suggesting would turn this site into a Yahoo answers.

Comment: @oded yes they downvote and punish users with low experience. I don't believe this is the right way to handle new users (like me). At least they should tolerate more.

Comment: New users are given a few opportunities to make mistakes and to recover from them (one can _always_ edit). If someone is not willing to learn, they can no longer participate. You might see it as punishment, but we have a lot of new users that do not have these problems.

Comment: @Oded I totaly agree with you that there are users who are more experienced and can do better questions than others and therefore they have no problems. But sometimes you really want to ask something that might can be a good question and help others and you are not allowed to do so . I know its not a forum here but it is a very trusted webservice that should tolerate also medium quality questions not only high.

Comment: We are going to have to disagree here. If someone asks (for example) 16 questions, 4 of which get deleted, and the rest have a single upvote between them and only 3 got answers, that means that they asked 9 questions that got no votes and no answers. Why should someone with such an asking history be allowed to ask more of the same?

Comment: @Oded because not all questions are the same. And by the end, if the questions are low quality they are ignored by the community, downvoted and therefore nobody reads them. Whatever you are in controll here I just say what I believe could make it a better service.

Comment: @Oded and lets say the user gets banned. What makes you think he will not create a second account to continue asking?

Comment: @theo231022 If a user consistently shows an inability to ask decent questions it's likely he/she won't change and should get banned to prevent more bad questions in the system. If the user want to change he/she can edit his/her questions to follow the guidelines and start asking good questions. Good questions (and answers) get upvotes which gives the user experience points which grant the user privileges on the site. Creating second account for asking questions hinder the user to receive such privileges.

Comment: @theo231022 _"if the questions are low quality they are ignored by the community, downvoted and therefore nobody reads them"_ . That's because users on this site put down time and effort to downvote and close these questions. There are way more people asking questions than reviewing them. We cannot simple just push work to other so that new users should be able to not work to make their questions well-received. If every user would search for information about their question, read the `How to ask` guidelines and proofread before posting, a majority of bad questions would be good or acceptable.